# Limit 'grep -rnw . -e "string_to_search"' to only display filenames and not the contents?

Tags: grep

```
grep -rnw . -e "string_to_search"
```

This command takes the input string mentioned above and lists all the files in the current directory (indicated by a dot) that contain that string.

The problem with this command is that it also lists the contents of the files, which is unnecessary for my purposes.

I only require the file names. Is there a way to achieve this?

Alternatively, is there a more efficient approach to optimize this task?

For example, if I need to search for this text within the logs of July only, where the logs are saved in the format `application.log_2023_07_*`, and today's log is saved as `application.log`.

Is there a better method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)’s `-l` flag limits the output to the names of files matching the pattern. You might as well drop the `-n` flag since it’s useless in that context:

```
grep -rlw . -e "string_to_search"
```

If you want to search only in a subset of files, drop the `-r` and list the files explicitly:

```
grep -lw -e "string_to_search" application.log_2023_07_*
```